# jquery css class problem

Tags: jquery, css, class

There are 2 classes for the same

tag. class .bt1 set as default in html code.

I need this p tag to change its class on click and save it, and when I click on this p tag I need it to be 'bt1i' class and 'bt1i' onclick function start working. Can someone help me to understand why it do not work and where is the error.  As I understand when I change the class in jquery code, it do not save for next call of jquery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $(".slide1").animate({marginRight:"-446px"}, 500 );
  $(".commonslide").animate({width:"206px", opacity:0}, 400 );
  $(".mainarea").animate({marginRight:"206px"}, 500);



 $(".bt1").click(function(){ 
     $(this).toggleClass("bt1i");
  $(".mainarea").animate({marginRight:"652px"}, 400);
  $(".sidebar").animate({marginRight:"0px"}, 400 );
        $(".slide1").animate({marginRight:"0px"}, 400 );
  $(".commonside").animate({width:"652px", opacity:1}, 400 );
 });




 $(".bt1i").click(function(){
  $(".slide1").animate({marginRight:"-446px"}, 500 );  
  $(".commonside").animate({width:"206px", opacity:1}, 400 );
  $(".mainarea").animate({marginRight:"206px"}, 500);
     $(this).toggleClass("bt1");  
 });


});
```

Comment: download FIREBUG.. it is a lifesaver for this stuff! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `.bt1i` handler to work via [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), like this:

```
$(".bt1").live('click', function(){ 
//and...
$(".bt1i").live('click', function(){
```

When you do `$(".bt1i").click(...)` it's looking for elements with a class of `bt1i` **at that time** and binding a `click` handler to them...the elements you're toggling the class on didn't have the class *then*.  With `.live()` it'll listen or elements with that class, no matter when they were added...the selector is evaluated at the time the event occurs.

As a side note if you want this to behave as expected, you need to toggle off the previous class as well, just add both to each [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) call, like this:

```
$(this).toggleClass("bt1 bt1i");
```

This will effectively swap the class on the element.

Comment: @Ahmed - Welcome :)  Be sure to accept answers to your question if they resolved the issue...if they didn't comment on what still isn't working :)

Answer (score 0):

Nick's answer is correct. Here is just another solution:

```
$(".bt1").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("bt1i")) {
        // add behavior for the bt1i class here
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("bt1i");
}
```

The reason you are having the problem is because jQuery's .click() function binds the handler only to the items that **currently** have the bt1i class. Since the class will not be added until later, the handler doesn't get bound to anything.